# I am trying to do a Pie charts in my ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, window, imagemagick, gruff

I am using the gem gruff in window 7 with docker, but when I try to write the g.data I get this error:

```
unable to read font `\Users\Raul del Rio\Desktop\grupo-43\Vera.ttf' @ error/annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1362
Extracted source (around line #32):


puts "mira para que revises"
puts g
g.write("pie_keynote.png")




Rails.root: /example
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:32:in `index'
```

and this is my code of articles_controller line 32:

```
g = Gruff::Pie.new
g.title = "Visual Pie Graph Test"
g.font="\\Users\\Raul del Rio\\Desktop\\grupo-43\\Vera.ttf"
g.data 'Fries', 20
g.data 'Hamburgers', 50
puts "mira para que revises"
puts g
g.write("pie_keynote.png")
```

and I really don't understand why the error :( and here is a photo of the app folder:

[image]

i also try the following:

```
g = Gruff::Pie.new
g.font=ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("Vera.ttf")
g.title = "Visual Pie Graph Test"
@datasets.each do |data|
  g.data(data[0], data[1])
end

# Default theme
g.write("pie_keynote.png")
```

and give me a weird error :

```
unable to read font `/assets/Vera-c4c45690b345435b2cba52ecabe275f05e49b389b39fe68ad03afbb551288d3d.ttf' @ error/annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1362
```

[image]

in another try i write in the .env file the following:

```
MAGICK_FONT_PATH=/Users/Raul del Rio/Desktop/grupo-43/Vera.ttf
```

and give me the next error:

```
Magick::ImageMagickError in ArticlesController#index 
unable to open file `/Users/Raul del Rio/Desktop/grupo-43/Vera.ttf/type.xml': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/FileToBlob/987
```

in another try i edit the .env again file with some modifications:

```
MAGICK_FONT_PATH=C:/Users/Raul del Rio/Desktop/grupo-43/font
```

and the screen error give me:

```
unable to open file `C:/Users/Raul del Rio/Desktop/grupo-43/font/type.xml': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/FileToBlob/987
```

and now i did a folder with font:

[image]

Comment: You have to explicitly tell `ImageMagick` what font to use.

Comment: like \app\assets\images or like C:\Users\juan\Desktop\grupo-43\app\assets\images or another thing?

Comment: The **font** is a set of glyphs used to represent symbols. Like this: https://github.com/topfunky/gruff/blob/0625ec81f37908d519e6a725a3140a42fb9aa2ee/test/gruff_test_case.rb#L143

Comment: so i have to add something like:
    `g.font = ' \app\assets\images\pie_keynote.png'`
    `g.write()'`

Comment: Rather than specifying a font by name, try using the full path to the actual font file with suffix.

Comment: can you give me an example :D pls?

Comment: you are getting close, the path you set up as ENV var is wrong. on windows paths start with something like "C:\". so in your case (example): MAGICK_FONT_PATH=C:\Users\juan\Desktop\grupo-43.

and make sure to not point to a single font, but a folder with fonts.

Comment: i do that i appear another error, i going to edit my question so you can see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally all the problems were solve using the following package in docker:

```
docker-compose run web install ghostscript
```

It seems that it establishes the routes between docker and windows. I really don't know how or why I need that, but work.

Here is where I found the information: https://github.com/docksal/docksal/issues/362

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/topfunky/gruff/blob/master/lib/gruff/base.rb#L218) it says to set an ENV var pointing to a path with fonts:

```
Looks for Bitstream Vera as the default font. Expects an environment var
# of MAGICK_FONT_PATH to be set. (Uses RMagick's default font otherwise.)
```

There is more info [here](http://imagemagick.sourceforge.net/http/www/QuickStart.html), but basically (on unix-like os) do something like:

```
export MAGICK_FONT_PATH=/path/to/fonts/dir
```

And on windows follow [these instructions](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm).

Comment: aaaa ok but what code i will have to puts to solve the problem? because i am so confused with what font puts and then what arg put in the write command? :/

Comment: the problem is outside of your code. The IM library is not finding fonts, probably because the ENV variable called MAGICK_FONT_PATH is not pointing to the right folder. Makes sense?

Comment: aaaa now make more sense, so i going to test the instruction for window to see if i understand how fix it

Comment: [here there is a photo of my folder](http://prntscr.com/k2c0l2) there is a file that have name .env that file can be making some trouble?

Comment: it might, if you are using dotenv https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv, you could add MAGICK_FONT_PATH in there as well. locate your font folder...